# Data structure returned by d3.csvParse

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

In d3.js the csvParse function works like:

```
d3.csvParse("foo,bar\n1,2\n2,3"); 
// [{foo: "1", bar: "2"}, {foo: "2", bar:"3"}, columns: ["foo", "bar"]]
```

**Q1**: What the structure name of the returned data? especially the "columns" properties?

Outside d3.js, if I do

```
var data = [{foo: "1", bar: "2"}, {foo: "2", bar:"3"}, columns: ["foo", "bar"]]
//uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token ':'
```

**Q2**: Why is the error? How to get around?

Comment: All your questions (q1, q2 and q3) are interconnected, however the question becomes too broad when you include q3. Please keep **just 1 problem** per question here at SO.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks for the tip and help. I move the q3 to this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309705/json-stringify-array-of-objects-with-property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you're seeing is just a regular JavaScript **array** and `columns` is simply a **property** of that array. In JavaScript, arrays can have properties.

If you have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/c625118fb35bdbbd28b4935834f18189408cbd59/src/dsv.js#L74), you'll see this:

```
var rows = []
```

And then:

```
rows.columns = columns || [];
```

Here is a very basic example:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.columns = "foo";
console.log(arr)
```

Look at your browser's console (not the snippet one), you'll see this (in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, columns: "foo"]
```

Regarding your error...

> //uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token ':'

... have in  mind that that is just the output in the console, that is **not** a valid array literal notation.

Answer (score -1):

Q1: The columns: ["foo","bar"] makes an error.
You can't assign the attribute columns if its not inside an object. What you can do instead is { columns: ["foo","bar"] }, which will crwate an object with the columns.